# HTML input type button cant send PHP Variable?

Tags: php, html

I Have table on browser Like This

```
  Name  | Action        |
________________________
Septiyo | Edit | Delete |
Fahmi   | Edit | Delete | 
Tejo    | Edit | Delete |
```

For Edit, usually I use link like this

```
  echo "<a href='edit.php?ID=$data['ID']'>Edit</a>";
```

With link, I can Include the ID variable and send to other Page.

The question is, if I change The Link with Button html. How can I include the variable?

My Button like this

```
 echo  "<input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='window.location=edit.php?ID=$data['ID']'>";
```

and it not Work.

Can anyone Help me?

Im very Appreciated your Answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not wrap your button in an `<a>` with the href set to the php page?

Like so:

```
echo <a href=yourPage.php><input type="button" value="Edit"></a>
```

A better option to consider might be taking out the `input` and styling the link to look like a button. It is standards compliant as well, where the other option may not be.

Comment: `a` elements may not have interactive content descendants which includes `input`

Comment: @Uchsun Thanks. :) Would you mind giving me an upvote as well? :)

Comment: If you go this way, why use a button at all? You might as well style the link so that it appears as a button.

Answer (score 2):

Do as this:

```
<a href='edit.php?ID=<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>'>Edit</a>
```

PHP is processed on the server side. So, it must know that the code you are writing is php and it knows when you put it inside the php tags `<?php  //php code   ?>`

That was just pointed the answer for the OP would be:

For you send data through a button you have some ways:

Call a function to do the redirection

put the value in a form and submit it.

With a form it would be:

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Another way would be through some javascript function:

```
<input 
  type="button" 
  onclick="javascript:window.open('edit.php?ID=<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>','','');">
```

And one more:

```
<script>
     function sendValue(id){
         window.location='edit.php?ID=' + id;
     }
</script>
<input 
  type="button" 
  onclick="javascript:sendValue('<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>')>
```

Comment: Oh yes Of course. I forget it. My COde inside the PHP so the code is inside the Echo

Comment: @JorgeCampos I Dont Know is  complicated if use the Button. But thanks for your Explanation. :)